# There is a way to get the XSSFSheet hash password?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

Someone knows why XSSFSheets doesn't provide a method to get its password like the HSSFSheet does with http://javadox.com/org.apache.poi/poi/3.13/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getPassword()

Answer (score 2):

The question is why would you need that unsafe short  two bytes "password hash"?

But:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

public class ExcelHSSFXSSFProtectedSheetPassword {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  Sheet sheet = hssfworkbook.createSheet();
  sheet.protectSheet("passwordExcel"); 

  short pwdHash = ((HSSFSheet)sheet).getPassword(); 
System.out.println(pwdHash);

  hssfworkbook.close();


  Workbook xssfworkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  sheet = xssfworkbook.createSheet();
  sheet.protectSheet("passwordExcel"); 

  byte[] pwdBytes = ((XSSFSheet)sheet).getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection().getPassword();
  pwdHash = java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(pwdBytes).order(java.nio.ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getShort();
System.out.println(pwdHash);

  xssfworkbook.close();

 }

}
```